# What does this Victorian sentence mean?

Tags: meaning, grammar, nineteenth-century-english

Talking about guns and shooting in the 19th century what does the following mean?

> I have seen no good shots among them ; and they look on a shot flying as a great performance.

Comment: Can you supply more context, or the reference to the quote ? A 'good shot' is a person who can shoot well, or it can be an admiration of a single instance of shooting - Oh ! Good shot !

Comment: Did you intend the portion after the question mark to be two separate sentences?

Answer (score 1):

*I have seen no good shots among them*

None of them are good ie skilled, at shooting

*and they look on a shot flying as a great performance.*

They regard any shot taken as good, presumably whether it hits the target or not.

Comment: Any shot 'flying', that is. So those people are even worse shots if even a shot not immediately going into the ground is a spectacle.